# How to install and run gupnp with gcc or g++

Tags: gcc, g++, gupnp

I am intended to work with gupnp which is a library for emulation of upnp device. I use ubuntu 16.04 and installed gupnp-tools package. But failed to run a program. For example when i try to run a c file with gupnp with gcc command, error come like libgupnp/gupnp.h header not found. How should i give command to run such program? Is further installation required?

Comment: are you sure you have included .h file in the program like `#include "libgnupnp/gupn.h";`? and post the code snippet in the question as well

Comment: Yes. And i have run sample code.